# Abstract name/title same indent as abstract text

Tags: titles, abstract

Im trying to make an abstract where the title of the abstract and the text are indented 12.7 mm left and right. So far I have done this for the text but since the abstract name follows the width of the normal page `\flushleft` does not work. How do I keep the same indent.

```
 \usepackage{abstract} 

 \setlength{\absleftindent}{12.7mm}\\

 \setlength{\absrightindent}{12.7mm}

 \setlength{\parindent}{12.7mm} % Do not indent the 1st line of a paragraph. 
 \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}   % Add space between paragraphs.


 %% redefine \footnoterule for using the whole text width
 \renewcommand\footnoterule{%  
 \kern-3\p@\hrule\@width\columnwidth\kern 2.6\p@ }


 % Begin document 
 \begin{document}


 \renewcommand*\abstractname{\flushleft\textbf{Abstract}\hfill}
 \begin{abstract} \noindent                 % Remove default indentation
 \textbf{
 \noindent Your abstract here \\ 
 Keywords: Your keywords here}
 \end{abstract}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the abstract as an `adjustwidth` block (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) which allows you to set the left/right indent as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{changepage}

\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
   \begin{adjustwidth}{12.7mm}{12.7mm}
   {\centering \textbf{\abstractname}\par}\medskip}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{12.7mm}{1pt}\hfill\rule{12.7mm}{1pt}% Just for this 

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \textbf{Keywords}: Your keywords here
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner, I see in your example that the title, "Abstract" is centred. However I would like to have "Abstract" in line with the text, so also indented with 12.7 mm.

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted the \centering and it worked like a charm :) Thanks so much, I would have never figured it out on my own!